# How to add custom attributes to option elements in symfony 2 form builder

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I am trying to add custom attributes to the option elements using the symfony2 form builder im im not sure that is natively possible. If its not I need to know how i would go about adding the functionality.

Take the following form as an example:

```
class FooForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('user','choice',array(
            'choices' => array(
                 'designers'=>'designers',
                 '1'=>'mike',
                 '2'=>'carroll',
                 'developers'=>'developers',
                 '3'=>'chase',
                 '4'=>'brett',
                 '5'=>'jordan',
             )
        ));
    }
}
```

then when rendered i need it to look like:

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled">designers</option>
    <option value="1">mike</option>
    <option value="2">carroll</option>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled">developers</option>
    <option value="3">chase</option>
    <option value="4">brett</option>
    <option value="5">jordan</option>
</select>
```

what i would expect would be something like:

```
class FooForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('user','choice',array(
            'choices' => array(
                 'designers'=>array(
                      'label'=>'designers',
                      'attr'=>arrry('disabled'=>'disabled')
                 ),
                 '1'=>'mike',
                 '2'=>'carroll',
                 'developers'=>array(
                      'label'=>'developers',
                      'attr'=>arrry('disabled'=>'disabled')
                 ),
                 '3'=>'chase',
                 '4'=>'brett',
                 '5'=>'jordan',
             )
        ));
    }
}
```

But that doesnt work. So any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to put attributes on options or you want to group your options? It seems that you are trying to group them.

Comment: Both, i found some grouping stuff in the source not sure how to do it. But i do also need to add some "data-id" attributes to the options as well

Comment: Attributes on option are not supported.. If you build a nested array of values you can create group of options (the key being the name of group). If you really need a way to add "data-id" you should probably create a new FormType that extends the [Entity form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) with a custom template.

Comment: Any idea on how to create a nested array using the 'entity' type with a query builder?

Comment: You tried the ["group by" option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by)? Basically you provide the field name that can be used to group entities together

Comment: Not sure how i missed that, well now they are grouped like they need to be. Not really sure how i would go about creating a new extensible formtype that would let me add custom options though.

Comment: This [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) should help you out, not saying it's easy but it's worth learning how it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39315/discussion-between-chausser-and-thomas-potaire)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its possible for `choice` since **2.7**. Look at [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-choice-form-type-refactorization). With `choice_attr`.

Comment: 2 years after I needed it they add it. Thanks for updating it

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create own widget, extended from 'choice' widget.

So you'll be able to use custom render on your options, and you'll be able to setup whatever you want in attributes to each option.

NB: I was looking the same, but 've used simple 'choice', and in template I've added JS var with extra options (array with values from the 'select', and specified extra attributes). I apply each extra attributes based on values of he option on page load event.

Answer (score -1):

Please use this below code for attribute set in symfony2

```
->add('birthdate', 'date',array(
      'input' => 'datetime',
      'widget' => 'single_text',
      'attr' => array('class'=>'calendar')
 ))
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, I was looking for a way to add attributes to each of the options in a choice field. Not on the parent field itself.